# Reputation Gain from binding acounts is not shown in the rep Graph

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, reputation-graph

Reputation Gain from binding the accounts on stackoverflow and meta.stackoverflow (+100) is not shown in the reputation Graphs of both sites. So my Reputation Graph is still 100 less than my current Reputation.

Is it supposed to be like this, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Reputation from bonuses will now be shown on the reputation graph (this was an unintentional side-effect actually, but fixes this old bug none the less).  For other info on these changes, see [Recent Reputation History Changes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123319/upcoming-reputation-history-changes).